# Add a new columns returning columns header meeting all conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

```
DF

ID  Mon Tue Wed Thur    Count_Y

1   Yes No  No  No  1

2   No  No  Yes No  1

3   No  No  No  No  0

4   No  Yes No  Yes 2

5   Yes Yes No  Yes 3

6   Yes Yes Yes Yes 4

7   No  No  Yes Yes 2
```

my script is

```
    DF1 <- DF %>%
     mutate ('New_Column' = case_when(`Mon` == "YES" ~ 'Mon', 
                                `Tue`=="YES" ~ 'Tue',
                                `Wed` =="YES" ~ 'Wed',`Thur`=="YES" ~ 'Thur'
                                ,TRUE ~ 'OFF'))
```

The final output is as seen below

```
ID  Mon Tue Wed Thur    Count_Y New_column
1   Yes No  No  No  1   Mon
2   No  No  Yes No  1   Wed
3   No  No  No  No  0   OFF
4   No  Yes No  Yes 2   Tue
4   No  Yes No  Yes 2   Thur
5   Yes Yes No  Yes 3   Mon
5   Yes Yes No  Yes 3   Tue
5   Yes Yes No  Yes 3   Thur
6   Yes Yes Yes Yes 4   Mon
6   Yes Yes Yes Yes 4   Tue
6   Yes Yes Yes Yes 4   Wed
6   Yes Yes Yes Yes 4   Thur
7   No  No  Yes Yes 2   Wed
7   No  No  Yes Yes 2   Thur
```

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Note that the comparisons in `case_when` are case sensitive, so based on your data you may want "Yes" instead of "YES"